# How to install postgis2.0 on Debian

Tags: postgis, postgresql

How to install postgis2.0 on Debian6.0 and with Postgressql9.1 ?
Didn't find any good repository ?
Do you have to go all the way and compile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo su in a terminal window and then sudo apt-get install postgis postgresql-9.1
That should work.

Comment: Nope because you get PostGIS1.5 not 2.0

Comment: 1.5 is better for functionality currently, I believe. "•The DebianGIS project has built PostGIS in the past, but is currently not very up-to-date."

Comment: Didn't know, do you have some reference where I can make up my mind. So maybe I'll stay 1.5

Comment: You could go unstable repostiory like you do for gis builds on ubuntu/debian.

Comment: Yes but being newbie in this, I wonder how unstable/stable is [ubuntuGIS](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable)

Comment: If you are doing a stable production it is not good (i.e. long term commercial or scientific database that needs to preserve data quality) but if you are experimenting as a new person it might be just the ticket.

Comment: intent is going production and also it is fairly basic... so I will take the safe bet and stay on 1.5. Thx

Answer (score 2):

I am using debian wheezy.
SMP Debian 3.2.57-3+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I followed the instructions from the postgres website to upgrade both postgresql and postgis as follows:

Create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list. The distributions are called codename-pgdg. In the example, replace wheezy with the actual distribution you are using:

deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wheezy-pgdg main

(You may determine the codename of your distribution by running lsb_release -c.)

wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 pgadmin3
sudo apt-get install postgis-2.1